# SQL Server data type text variable with HTML data query

Tags: sql-server

I would really appreciate if anyone can help or point me in the right direction for a Microsoft SQL Server query problem.

I am working with a Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure that has a `text` data type variable declared. The stored procedure is invoked by a click button in a web front end page. Data grabbed by the variable is stored in html format.

Through SQL Server query analyser, trace shows the following information

```
@var1 = '<tag1><tag2 /><tag3 field1="" field2="some data" /></tag1>'
```

I am trying to query the information held in the variable but having no success. this is what I have tried;

```
set ansi nulls on 
go

set quoted_identifier on
go

alter procedure dbo.procedureX
    @var0 varchar(10) 
    @var1 text
AS
begin
    set nocount on

    --attempt 1
    if @var1 LIKE '%data%'
    begin
        ;throw 50001,'hi, data here',1;
        return;
    end

    set nocount off
end
```

Is it possible to interact with text variable in this scenario?

Thank you

Regards,

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: hi, thank you for the feedback. i imagine developers are working on this. im not a developer but assisting with a few minor customisation.